# ORACLE stored procedure - Store query result

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP 
(
   query IN VARCHAR2(200),
   CURSOR_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
  row_ PROCESSED_DATA_OBJECT; 
  processed PROCESSED_DATA_TABLE;
BEGIN

       .....

END;
```

with

```
CREATE TYPE processed_data_obj AS OBJECT(
  id   INTEGER,
  value FLOAT
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE processed_data_table AS TABLE OF processed_data_obj;
/
```

I call the stored procedure passing the query to be executed as input parameter.
The query is something like that:

```
SELECT A,B FROM TABLE WHERE
```

where A,B and TABLE are not fixed (defined at runtime during java program execution), so I don't know their values in advance.

How could I fetch/store each returned row in my structure?

```
processed PROCESSED_DATA_TABLE;
```

Thanks

Comment: From what I understood from your question, you'll have to resort to dynamic sql. Bad news, is, you won't be able to use Native Dynamic SQL (through EXECUTE IMMEDIATE),  you'll have to resort to something called Method 4, using the DBMS_SQL package (investigate). If indeed, that's the way to go, it won't be an easy task. Good luck

Comment: "where A,B and TABLE are not fixed ". Is it fixed that there will always be two columns, an integer and a number? Or could the projection have more or fewer columns?

Comment: @APC There will be always 2 columns. The name of the columns and the table could be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you can process a dynamically generated query into a user defined type. Note that, in order for this to work, the structure of your query (columns) must match the data type structure of your type (attributes) otherwise you're in for trouble.

```
CREATE TYPE processed_data_obj AS OBJECT(
  ID   INTEGER,
  VALUE FLOAT,

  constructor FUNCTION processed_data_obj RETURN self AS result
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY processed_data_obj IS
    constructor FUNCTION processed_data_obj RETURN self AS result IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE processed_data_table AS TABLE OF processed_data_obj;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp (
   p_query  IN VARCHAR2
) AS
  cursor_       sys_refcursor;
  processed     processed_data_table := processed_data_table();
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor_ FOR p_query;
    loop
        processed.EXTEND;
        processed(processed.count) := processed_data_obj();
        fetch cursor_ INTO processed(processed.count).ID, processed(processed.count).VALUE;
        exit WHEN cursor_%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(processed(processed.count).ID||' '||processed(processed.count).VALUE);-- at this point do as you please with your data.
    END loop;
    CLOSE cursor_; -- always close cursor ;)
    processed.TRIM; -- or processed.DELETE(processed.count);
END sp;
```

I noticed that, originally, you did put `CURSOR_` as an output parameter in your stored procedure, if that is still your goal, you can create your procedure as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp (
    p_query  IN VARCHAR2,
    cursor_  out sys_refcursor
) AS
    processed     processed_data_table := processed_data_table();
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor_ FOR p_query;
    loop
        processed.EXTEND;
        processed(processed.count) := processed_data_obj();
        fetch cursor_ INTO processed(processed.count).ID, processed(processed.count).VALUE;
        exit WHEN cursor_%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(processed(processed.count).ID||' '||processed(processed.count).VALUE);-- at this point do as you please with your data.
    END loop;
    -- cursor remains open
    processed.TRIM; -- or processed.DELETE(processed.count);
END sp;
```

In this case just be conscious about handling your cursor properly and always close it when you're done with it.

Comment: I tried your code and it is what i was looking for. Just a question: `SELECT * FROM TABLE (processed)` gives me last record equals `null`. Have I add an `if` on the cursor status before performing `processed.EXTEND` and `processed... := ... ` ?

Comment: Good to hear it worked for you. About conditioning the `EXTEND`, it'll be hard to know when to stop extending the collection as the only way to know would be to wait for `FETCH` to reach the EOF for `CURSOR_`, but since the collection needs to be extended/instantiated to receive the fetched values (otherwise you would raise a `Reference to Uninitialized Composite` exception) this would be a problem, I rather recommend issuing a `processed.TRIM` or a `processed.DELETE(processed.count)` instruction after the end of loop, to remove collection's last element. I've updated my answer to demonstrate

Comment: Of course another way of knowing how many elements you are expecting from the query could be to iterate through it with local variables (not the collection) retrieve count either by cursor's `rowcount` attribute or a local counter, and then just as you were saying, condition the collection's extends inside the fetch-into-collection cycle. Good luck.